# when to instantiate masterdata?

Tags: c#, master-data-management

when should I instantiate my masterdata ( represents the business objects which are agreed on and shared across the enterprise) classes? I have following project layers:

- web interface
- web api
- wcf service
- businessLogic
- data access layer

Should I make a own class and instantiate all my masterdata classes at once?